# Jquery in views

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it OK (It's working OK but is it proper?) if I place jquery code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
</script>
```

in my app/views/show.html.rb ?

Is it better to put it somewhere else? I didn't want to put it in layout because I don't need it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would put that piece of script into an external JS file and call it from the header of my page in my layout - this way you are keeping your markup and your Javascript entirely separate (in much the same way that you would put all your CSS in an external CSS file and not in style attributes).

But there is no harm in having it where it is. It's really up to you whether you feel it is worth the time and effort to move the script into an external file.

Comment: If I move that file to an external .js file where should I include that? In the layout/application? I think that is not proper because it will load for every page. And I only need it for 1a view. Do I miss something?

Comment: However, you should note that for performance reasons, an extra request for such little content will be very deficient.

Comment: @ntenisOT I think it's fine to include the JS file in your common header. Again I like to think of it like CSS - not all the rules in your CSS file are used on every page, but you wouldn't only include some CSS on pages where it is used.

Comment: @passcod Most browsers cache JS files in much the same way as they cache images, so they won't make repeat requests to the JS file once they have downloaded it the first time.

Comment: Re incl. in common: yes, except if there is a conflict. Re cache: true if majority of users are returning to site. But good answer overall.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's better if you put your code in a `.js` file and include it only when you need it.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: include this code to a js and add this code in the show.html.rb using the javascript include tag?